# Google Maps API region biasing Europe

Tags: google-maps

According to the [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes) you can bias the results using a region code, specified as a [IANA language region subtag](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry). When looking at that second link you'll see that there is a region subtag EU for Europe, which was added on 2009-07-29. However none of the 2 code samples below seems to follow this biasing. When I geocode "Hoboken" I get Hoboken in the US, rather than Hobken in Belgium, EU.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'EU'}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
    else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

or using the region parementer in the URL:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;region=EU"></script>
```

Comment: I'm also having the same issue trying to specify `'US'` or `'US-CT'` to limit my searches to Connecticut. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I've reported the bug to Google and have a similar question with more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277068/google-geocode-region-works-only-in-certain-cases

Answer (score 0):

Use a component restriction instead, these restrict the search to the parameter specified.

Geocoder component restrictions are defined as so :

```
componentRestrictions: {
  country: 'BE'
}
```

So your call would now be :

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'EU', componentRestrictions: {
  country: 'BE'
}
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
  }
  else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderComponentRestrictions

Comment: Not really what I am/was looking for. As then it would always prioritize Hoboken Belgium over Hoboken Netherlands (if that existed and was more common)